# How to consider one key among composite primary keys in a table as a foreign key in a another table in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgres i am creating a table with multiple primary keys

```
CREATE TABLE tab1(
col_1 int,
col_2 txt,
col_3 txt,
PRIMARY KEY (col_1,col_2)
);
```

I am trying refer one of the primary in table "tabl" as foreign key in another table

```
CREATE TABLE tab2 (
col_4 int,
col_5 txt,
col_6 numeric(5,2),
PRIMAY KEY (col_4),
CONSTRAINT fk_tab1 FOREIGN KEY(col_5) REFERENCES tab1(col_1) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

But when i am trying to do this i am getting error as below

```
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "tab1"
SQL state: 42830
```

How can i take one key among multiple primary keys in one table as foreign key in another table.

Comment: It's actually called a *composite primary key* or *multi-column primary key*, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary key (PK) mentions two columns. PKs enforce uniqueness, and multicolumn primary keys enforce uniqueness on the *combination* of the two columns. Example:

```
col_1       col_2
1           Michael         OK
2           Stonebraker     OK
3           Michael         OK
2           Stonebraker     NOT ALLOWED -- duplicate PK values
```

If you want your `col_1` and `col_2` columns to separately contain unique values -- unique UserIds and unique names for example  -- define your PK on just one of them and a UNIQUE key on the other. If you do that, you can reference either column as a foreign key (FK).

And, when you want to make an outbound FK reference from `tab2` to a column in `tab1`, you must define that column in that table as a single-column PK or a UNIQUE key.  Maybe like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tab1(
  col_1 int PRIMARY KEY,
  col_2 text UNIQUE,
  col_3 text
);
```

But be careful making text columns UNIQUE. They can be very very long, and enforcing uniqueness on vast amounts of text can cause performance trouble.